# Multiple keywords database search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search

I am currently using scopes in my model to perform searches within a database.  I can stack these scopes and it will output results matching all parameters.

```
scope :search_between, lambda{|begin_date, end_date|
  where "sub.date BETWEEN ? AND ?", begin_date, end_date
}
```

What I am having trouble with is integrating a keywords search that will search the entire database and output the results that contain the sum of the keywords.  I would like to do something like this (displayed for simplicity):

```
scope :keywords, lambda{|search|
  search.chomp.split(/,\s*/) do |item|
    where "date like ? or city like ? or state like ?", "%#{item}%" and
    where "date like ? or city like ? or state like ?", "%#{item}%" and
    where "date like ? or city like ? or state like ?", "%#{item}%"
  end
}
```

I am currently using something like this to take care of searching multiple columns:

```
scope :keywords, lambda{|search|
  search.chomp.split(/,\s*/) do |item|
    where(Sub.column_names.map {|cn| "#{cn} like ?" }.join("or "), "%#{item}%"]  Sub.column_names.size)).join(' AND ')
  end
}
```

My problem is that I want to do multiple "where()'s" in the scope. Is it possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn it into a method that returns a scope:

```
def self.keywords(search)
  scope = self.scoped
  search.chomp.split(/,\s*/).each do |item|
    scope = scope.where(["date  like ? or 
                          city  like ? or 
                          state like ?", "%#{item}%","%#{item}%","%#{item}%"])
  end
  scope
end
```

The drawback is that you can't chain keywords off of other scopes, but you can chain other scopes off of keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be hitting the limit with using the database for full text search.

Have you looked into using [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) for your full text searches? There's also IndexTank if you want to use a 3rd party service.

For solr, there are rubygems available to help you: [sunspot](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot), [solrsan](https://github.com/tc/solrsan)(i'm the author)

Sunspot is definitely more full-featured and solrsan is a barebones layer.

Comment: Honestly, I was trying to do something that did not require me to install anything on the server